# Lumen first install - ReflectionException: Class redis does not exist

Tags: laravel, lumen

I am playing around with Lumen, I installed it via Lumen installer. After I do `composer install`, I try to use `artisan` but it throws the following error:

```
ReflectionException: Class redis does not exist in Container.php on line 752
```

My composer.json:

```
"require": {
        "php": ">=7",
        "ext-pdo_pgsql": "*",
        "ext-soap": "*",
        "guzzlehttp/guzzle": "^6.3",
        "laravel/lumen-framework": "5.5.*",
        "laravel/tinker": "^1.0",
        "vlucas/phpdotenv": "~2.2"
    },
    "require-dev": {
        "barryvdh/laravel-ide-helper": "^2.4",
        "doctrine/dbal": "^2.5"
    },
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you using redis anywhere in your project??

Comment: @Sohel0415 no, this is just a fresh install.

Comment: try `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @Sohel0415 I tried it, didn't work.

Comment: try creating new project with `composer create-project --prefer-dist laravel/lumen projectName`

Comment: It did not work but I found the problem.

Comment: I use docker for developement and there was a cache_driver environment defined. Silly mistake.

Answer (score 11):

I had the same.

Solution:

```
composer require illuminate/redis
```

Register it in bootstrap/app.php by calling

```
$app->register(Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class);
```

in the file, under Register Service Providers.

From [this aricle](https://thewebtier.com/laravel/getting-started-redis-lumen/).

Answer (score 0):

From Lumen's official documentation at https://lumen.laravel.com/docs/7.x/cache :

**Redis Support:**

Before using a Redis cache with Lumen, you will need to install the `illuminate/redis` package via Composer. Then, you should register the Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider in your bootstrap/app.php file:

`$app->register(Illuminate\Redis\RedisServiceProvider::class);`

If you have not called `$app->withEloquent()` in your bootstrap/app.php file, then you should call `$app->configure('database');` in the bootstrap/app.php file to ensure the Redis database configuration is properly loaded.